# Chef: Uploading modified cookbook not working?

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to modify and upload a cookbook to my Chef server but when I try that, it looks like the recipe inside the cookbook is not changed in Chef server.

I am using a Win2K8 machine as my workstation, and I edit the learn_chef_iis-0.2.0\recipes\default.rb.  I then do:

> knife cookbook delete learn_chef_iis

then:

> knife cookbook upload learn_chef_iis

and when I look at the default.rb in the opcode web app, it still shows the same default.rb (i.e., my changes are not there).

I've seen some suggestions to change the version of the cookbook and I've tried that by editing the metadata.rb "version", but even when I do that, when I do the "knife cookbook upload" I still end up with the same version (0.2.0) and with the unmodified default.rb.

HELP!!!  I've been working on this for awhile today and am stuck :(!!

Thanks,

### Jim

> PS C:\Users\Administrator\chef-repo\learn_chef_iis-0.2.0> knife cookbook upload learn_chef_iis
>
> Uploading learn_chef_iis [0.2.0]
>
> Uploaded 1 cookbook.
>
> PS C:\Users\Administrator\chef-repo\learn_chef_iis-0.2.0> knife cookbook upload learn_chef_iis --force
>
> Uploading learn_chef_iis [0.2.0]
>
> Uploaded 1 cookbook.
>
> PS C:\Users\Administrator\chef-repo\learn_chef_iis-0.2.0>

EDIT:

Here's the modified default.rb.  Is this ok?  Maybe this default.rb is bad so it causes the "knife upload" to fail?

```
#
# Cookbook Name:: learn_chef_iis
# Recipe:: default
#
# Copyright (C) 2014
#
#
#
powershell_script 'Install IIS' do
  code <<-EOH
  Import-Module ServerManager
  Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server
  EOH
  guard_interpreter :powershell_script
  not_if "(Get-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Server).InstallState -eq 'Installed'"
end

service 'w3svc' do
  action [:enable, :start]
end

template 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Default.htm' do
  source 'index.html.erb'
end
```

and, here's a run with "verbose" output:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\chef-repo> knife cookbook upload learn_chef_iis -V
INFO: Using configuration from C:/Users/Administrator/chef-repo/.chef/knife.rb
Uploading learn_chef_iis [0.2.0]
INFO: Validating ruby files
INFO: Validating templates
INFO: Syntax OK
INFO: Saving learn_chef_iis
INFO: Uploading files
INFO: Upload complete!
Uploaded 1 cookbook.
PS C:\Users\Administrator\chef-repo>
```

EDIT 3:

I don't have an explanation, but I created a new cookbook following:

http://learn.chef.io/learn-the-basics/windows/make-your-recipe-more-manageable/

This one is named "iis".

Then I did "knife cookbook upload iis" and that worked, and I did "chef-client -o "recipe[iis]" on the node and that worked.

I then modified the recipe slightly and did the knife upload and chef-client again and saw the updated info on the IIS.

So, the new cookbook seems to be working and updating.

Strange :(???

Comment: i'm guessing you are running the knife command from a different directory than your updated cookbook is in.  Please validate that, after that simply running `knife upload learn_chef_iis --force` will definitely work.  Make sure to clear your cache since the chef web API has some caching issues.  on Mac a `Command + R` works or on windows `Control + Shift + F5`  Here is a link to the API https://docs.chef.io/knife_upload.html

Comment: Can you paste the console output after you run the `knife upload` command?

Comment: also noticed you are saying you are using `knife cookbook upload learn_chef_iis` it should be `knife upload learn_chef_iis`

Comment: Both with the --force and without the --force, I still don't see the changed file/recipe in the opcode web app.

Comment: have you tried it without the word `cookbook`? are you running powershell as admin? can you run the same command from `C:\Users\Administrator\chef-repo` instead of `C:\Users\Administrator\chef-repo\learn_chef_iis-0.2.0`

Comment: @abc123 - took me awhile to see the difference you were citing (no cookbook) but I tried both ways and the same problem (no changes in Chef server/web app).  I also tried in the chef-repo dir and in the learn_chef_iis dir and same thing (no change).  The thing that is really driving me nuts is that I think that I was able to get a modified recipe ONCE earlier today, but haven't been able to do that again almost all day today.

Comment: @JamesTaylor - what I posted was all that appears when I run the "knife cookbook upload".

Comment: Hm. More questions: Has it ever worked with `knife cookbook upload` before? Will it just not update? Have you tried deleting it off the chef server and doing the reupload? Are you sure you edited the `metadata.rb` file in the cookbook and that you are in cookbook when you run the `upload` command?

Comment: @JamesTaylor - It worked ONCE, earlier today (this morning).  Yes, I tried deleting (knife cookbook delete) then upload (knife cookbook upload and knife upload).  What do you mean "edited the metadata.rb"?  I've tried both in dir chef-repo and inside the specific cookbook dir (learn_chef_iis).

Comment: @JamesTaylor - FYI, the file I have been modifying is the recipes/default.rb file (as posted in the OP).  BUT I have edited the metdata.rb by changing the value of the version to "0.2.1" but Chef/knife still think the cookbook version is 0.2.0.  That was why I asked how do i change the cookbook version.

Comment: Sorry i just edited the OP again to show the modified default.rb.  I could've sworn that I posted that earlier, but it looks like it didn't persist.  The one with the EOH is the modified one.

Comment: can you name the folder to match the name of the `metabase.rb` that you gave the cookbook?  If you'd like to screenshare real quick i'd be happy to help.  So change the folder name to `learn_chef_iis` from `learn_chef_iis-0.2.0`

Comment: @abc123 - tried changing the dir name as you suggested.  Same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what you describe your probably have 2 entries in your `knife.rb` for the `cookbook_path` setting (it takes an array) [See the doc](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife.html).

I'm pretty sure the original cookbook is on the last path listed in the `cookbook_path` so knife upload don't fail but it upload the unmodified version.

When you're unsure of where you're living or if you wish to upload a cookbook from a path not in the `cookbook_path` you can override this setting with `-o .` when you're on the parent directory for the cookbook or `-o /absolut/path/to/parent/dir/`.

When you're unsure about a command type it without arguments, the help will be displayed.

```
>knife cookbook upload
USAGE: knife cookbook upload [COOKBOOKS...] (options)
    -a, --all                        Upload all cookbooks, rather than just a single cookbook
    -s, --server-url URL             Chef Server URL
        --chef-zero-host HOST        Host to start chef-zero on
        --chef-zero-port PORT        Port to start chef-zero on
    -k, --key KEY                    API Client Key
        --[no-]color                 Use colored output, defaults to false on Windows, true otherwise
        --concurrency NUMBER_OF_THREADS
                                     How many concurrent threads will be used
    -c, --config CONFIG              The configuration file to use
    -o, --cookbook-path PATH:PATH    A colon-separated path to look for cookbooks in
        --defaults                   Accept default values for all questions
        --include-dependencies       Also upload cookbook dependencies
    -d, --disable-editing            Do not open EDITOR, just accept the data as is
    -e, --editor EDITOR              Set the editor to use for interactive commands
    -E, --environment ENVIRONMENT    Set ENVIRONMENT's version dependency match the version you're uploading.
        --force                      Update cookbook versions even if they have been frozen
    -F, --format FORMAT              Which format to use for output
        --freeze                     Freeze this version of the cookbook so that it cannot be overwritten
    -z, --local-mode                 Point knife commands at local repository instead of server
    -u, --user USER                  API Client Username
        --print-after                Show the data after a destructive operation
    -V, --verbose                    More verbose output. Use twice for max verbosity
    -v, --version                    Show chef version
    -y, --yes                        Say yes to all prompts for confirmation
    -h, --help                       Show this message
```

And when you're wondering what it does or where it search for something, run knife in verbose mode with `-VV` which gives you a lot of informations:

Extract of an upload with -VV:

```
[...] 
Uploading company-collectd   [0.1.0]
DEBUG: Versions of cookbook 'collectd' returned by the server: 1.1.2
DEBUG: Matched cookbook 'collectd' with constraint '>= 0.0.0' to cookbook version '1.1.2' on the server
DEBUG: No chefignore file found at d:/chef/repo/cookbooks/chefignore no files will be ignored
INFO: Validating ruby files
DEBUG: Ruby file d:/chef/repo/cookbooks/company-collectd/attributes/default.rb is unchanged, skipping syntax check
DEBUG: Ruby file d:/chef/repo/cookbooks/company-collectd/metadata.rb is unchanged, skipping syntax check
DEBUG: Ruby file d:/chef/repo/cookbooks/company-collectd/recipes/default.rb is unchanged, skipping syntax check
INFO: Validating templates
INFO: Syntax OK
[...]
```

Comment: which knife.rb would I check about the cookbook_path?  I searched and there're a number of knife.rb files on the workstation machine.  Thanks, Jim

Comment: Read your logs: "INFO: Using configuration from C:/Users/Administrator/chef-repo/.chef/knife.rb" quoted from your question

Comment: here's that knife.rb:  # See https://docs.getchef.com/config_rb_knife.html for more information on knife configuration options

current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "jimxxxxxx"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/jimxxxxxx.pem"
validation_client_name   "chefadmins-validator"
validation_key           "#{current_dir}/chefadmins-validator.pem"
chef_server_url          "https://chefserver.whatever.com/organizations/chefadmins"
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]

Comment: your modified cookboock is right under `[whatever]/chef-repo` and you're there. The knife parameter is `cookbook_path ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]` i.e: `C:/Users/Administrator/chef-repo/cookbooks/` and that's here that knife search for cookbook when you ask to upload them. ReRead the tutorials about the chef-repo and it's structure.

Comment: given what you said, then the original problem is still a puzzle, i.e., why it was not uploading the updated recipe, right?  The updated recipe was definitely in c:\...\Administrator\chef-repo\learn_chef_iis-0.2.0\recipes\default.rb, and yet when I modified that default.rb and did the "knife upload" or "knife cookbook upload" (which said they worked ok) the updated default.rb was not showing in the opcode web app.

Comment: Because the original cookbook is in"C:/Users/Administrator/chef-repo/cookbooks/learn_chef_iis" and that's the one in this directory knife find and upload, this one you never touched as you're modifying a file out of the cookbook_path. Note the **cookbooks** at end of the path as it seems you didn't noticed it in my previous comment.

Comment: YOU NAILED IT :)!  Sorry that I didn't notice this before but there was actually a ...Administrator\learn_chef_iis\recipes\default.rb AND a ...Administrator\cookbooks\learn_chef_iis\recipes\default.rb, and I was editing the former one (the one NOT under the cookbooks dir).  I don't know how that other directory got there :(, but I am happy that this mystery seems to be solved thanks to you (and to others)!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your chef repo is essentially structured something like this:

```
cookbooks/your_cookbook
```

Containing:

```
metadata.rb
recipes/default.rb
providers/
resources/
```

If you incremented the version number in `metadata.rb` and are sure you are running

```
knife cookbook upload
```

in the directory, everything should work. [At least that's what the docs say](https://docs.chef.io/knife_cookbook.html).

Or you could try to back out of that directory into your main directory of your chef repo and run:

```
knife upload cookbooks
```

or

```
knife upload /
```

[Again, that's what the docs say.](https://docs.chef.io/knife_upload.html)

But I don't have a lot of experience using this. [I use Berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com/) which is essential a dependency management tool that's a lot more seemless than [Librarian-Chef](http://rafecolton.com/chef/2013-05-20-librarian-chef-vs-berkshelf.html), in my opinion.

Simply navigate to your cookbook, run:

```
berks init
```

and then when you make changes run through:

```
berks install
berks upload
```

to push your cookbooks to your chef repo, after updating your version number in your `metadata.rb` file.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: The "knife upload cookbooks" and "knife upload /" worked the same way (problem).

Comment: When I try the "berks init" I get an error saying that "does not appear to be a valid cookbook".